# Image of a ray under a complex map

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f(z) = \frac{1}{2}( z+ z^{-1})$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$. We want to see what the image of a ray in the complex plane is under this map.

So let $z = re^{i\theta}$. Then: $$f(re^{i\theta}) = \frac{1}{2}(re^{i\theta} + r^{-1}e^{-i\theta}) = \frac{r^2+1}{2r}\cos\theta + \frac{r^2-1}{2r}i \sin \theta$$ by some simple algebraic manipulation. (I found this form particularly useful to find the image of circles centered at the origin under this map, which are ellipses unless it is the unit circle.)

So now to find the image of a ray, fix $\theta$. If $\theta = 0, \frac{\pi}{2}, \pi,$ or $\frac{3\pi}{2}$, it's pretty easy to see that the map actually fixes these rays. I've used some graphing software to see that the image of something like $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$ is a hyperbola, but I'm not sure what the general case should be like.